# When using Authorize.net, should the billing address be passed to the capture method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

We're already passing billing address to the authorize method. Should the billing address still be passed to the capture method later?

Example:

```
response = gateway.authorize(1000, credit_card, options_with_billing_address)
gateway.capture(1000, response.authorization, options_with_billing_address)
```

or no need to pass the billing address to the capture method? Like:

```
response = gateway.authorize(1000, credit_card, options_with_billing_address)
gateway.capture(1000, response.authorization)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the billing address, to capture a previously authorized amount using authOnlyTransaction. Though, the transactionType should be priorAuthCaptureTransaction and the **refTransId**(Transaction ID of the original authorization transaction) field is required.